# how to completely delete schema data after uninstall mysql worbench on ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, workbench

i deleted my workbench application completely with synaptic package and installed a fresh workbench. when i opened it, all old DB's (with tables) that have been preserved showed again. so if the workbench save my old data on my ubuntu where is it so i can delete it?
just for give you more details i already delete cache and even the /.mysql/workbench/ folder and it's not helped.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL Workbench is just a program to interface with your MySQL instance, so uninstalling it won't delete any of your data or structures. If you want to completely wipe everything in the instance, probably the easiest way is to uninstall, then reinstall mysql-server, like so:

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server && sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

If you have packages that depend on it, you can delete all databases through the command-line interface instead. Make sure you have mysql-client installed, then open a terminal and type

```
mysql -u root -p
```

You will be prompted for the root password, and then you will be presented with the interactive prompt. Type

```
show databases;
```

to get the list of databases in the instance, then type

```
drop database `<database name>`;
```

for each database in the list (besides information_schema). Press Ctrl-D, and you're done!